# Question about Vector Space and Sub space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $A = \{(x, y, z, w) \in \mathbb F^4 | x - 3y + w = -7\}$. Is $A$ a vector space? Is it a subspace?

I just want to confirm if I am doing it right or not.

For $A$ to be a vector space, it must satisfy closure property w.r.t addition.

Let $a_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1, w_1)$ and $a_2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2, w_2)$.

$$\tag{1} x_1 - 3y_1 + w_1 = -7,$$

$$\tag{2}x_2 - 3y_2 + w_2 = -7,$$

$$a_1 + a_2 = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2, w_1 + w_2)$$

$$a_1 + a_2 = (x_1 + x_2) - 3 ( y_1 + y_2) + (w_1 + w_2) = -7$$

$a_1 + a_2$ is an element of $A$. Adding (1) and (2) we get,

$$(x_1 + x_2) - 3(y_1 + y_2) + (w_1 + w_2) = -14.$$

$a_1 + a_2$ is not an element of $A$. Hence $A$ is not a vector space and not a subspace.

Is it right?

Comment: You must find a couterexample. Note that your set doesn’t contain (0,0,0). Thus it is not a subspace.

Comment: The set does not contain (0, 0, 0, 0). So, 0 - 3 (0) + 0 = -7 does not hold true. Therefore, it is not a vector space. Is this right?

Comment: yes. That is all you have to say

Comment: Alright, thanks mate. One more question, if some set is not a vector space, then it is not a subspace either. Is this right?

Comment: A subspace of a vector space is by definition a vector space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're not doing it right. Your work isn't necessarily incorrect but you've missed the point of the exercise.

The given set does not contain the element $(0,0,0,0)$. Hence, it is not subspace of $\mathbb{F}^4$. It is not even a vector space if we're considering entry-wise scalar multiplication and vector addition.

You've kind of missed some important steps. In order to check if something is a vector space, you need to check a whole bunch of different axioms (8 different axioms, depending on the book that you learnt from). In order to check if something is a subspace of a given vector space, you need to just check that it satisfies closure under both operations and contains the additive identity of the vector space. You should review these definitions before doing more problems.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the absence of zero vector here as well. However, to prove that it is not a vector space is it not enough to prove that closure property does not hold? Because closure property is the first axiom.

Comment: Yes but it takes much more effort to do that than to just assert that the zero vector isn't in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Every Vector Subspace must contain the origin.
The lines and planes that pass through the origin form vector subspaces.

Comment: The set does not contain (0, 0, 0, 0). So, 0 - 3 (0) + 0 = -7 does not hold true. Therefore, it is not a vector space. Is this right?

Comment: The plane does not pass through the origin. Only planes of the form $ax+by+cz=0$ pass through the origin